Robber dressed as a clown and black flips down the hallway
looking for a movie my dad watched when I was a kid between 99-2000 movie could be older but seems from the 90s
All I can remember is at the beginning a guy and girl attempt to rob a gas station the cops arrive, and they have a shoot out and the girl is killed and I believe the man was too.
The guy comes back from the dead to kill the cop. I also remember a few parts of the end the cop and the robber end up in a school at one point the robber was dressed as a clown and black flips down the hallway at the very end. The robber is having a flashback of the gas station and he finds out he is actually the one who shot his girlfriend so he let's the cop go.
As the cop is leaving the robber puts a gun in his mouth and shoots himself.

Judge and Jury (1996)

Wanted killer Joseph Meeker is sent to the electric chair after being
  caught during a liquor store holdup. But Meeker returns from the dead,
  taunting and pursuing Michael Silvano, the former cop who apprehended
  him during the robbery, determined to obtain revenge for Silvano's
  accidental shooting of his girlfriend during the holdup.

Final scene

